# Merging list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine the following python list comprehensions into a single line? I know it's not necessary, I'm just curious.

```
rows = [row.split() for row in data]
flattened = [float(val) for sublist in rows for val in sublist]
```

Below is a snippet of the data file,

```
['  -.2098335E-03  -.2108988E-03  -.2119629E-03  -.2130240E-03  -.2140826E-03', '  -.2151421E-03  -.2161973E-03  -.2172531E-03  -.2183025E-03  -.2193489E-03', '  -.2203825E-03  -.2214097E-03  -.2224521E-03  -.2235475E-03  -.2246843E-03'....]
```

I'm trying to extract each of the strings and make a single list of numbers. The code above currently does that, I was wanting to see if it could get even more condensed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what `data` is?

Comment: does this help? `[float(val) for sublist in [row.split() for row in data] for val in sublist]`

Comment: edit your question include your data and how you wanna get your output, and what you hav done till

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nested List Comprehensions

Nested List Comprehensions are nothing but a `list comprehension` within another `list comprehension` which is quite similar to `nested for loops`.

When we create a `new list` (of squares) from the elements of the `existing list`, using `list comprehensions`, we write:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[i**2 for i in l1]
print(l2)
```

This gives the **output**:

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

**We can also nest two or even more `for loops` in this comprehension.**

**For example:**

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6]
l3=[[i**2,j**2] for i in l1 for j in l2]
print(l3)
```

**The output:**

```
[[1, 16], [1, 25], [1, 36], [4, 16], [4, 25], [4, 36], [9, 16], [9, 25], [9, 36]]
```

**Similarly:**

```
l1=[1,2]
l2=[3,4]
l3=[5,6]
l4=[[i,j,k] for i in l1 for j in l2 for k in l3]
print(l4)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

**Similarly** your code can be re-written using the help of `list comprehensions` as:

```
flattened = [float(val) for sublist in (row.split() for row in data) for val in sublist]
```

Hope this helped you!

Answer (score 2):

Since `sublist` is your `row.split()`, simply replace it.

```
data = ['0.3 0.6 0.9', '0.1 0.4 0.3']

flattened = [float(val) for row in data for val in row.split()]

print(flattened) #[0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3]
```

If we expand it, it becomes more clear.

```
data = ['0.3 0.6 0.9', '0.1 0.4 0.3']

#the generator is identically replacing this part
flattened = list()
for row in data:
    for val in row.split():
        flattened.append(float(val))
```

All of the answers that suggest the solution below, are trying to wrap the source loop with the content loop.

```
#               v--contents--v      wrapping       v--source       
[float(val) for sublist in (row.split() for row in data) for val in sublist]
```

It should be the other way around.

```
[float(val) for row in data for val in row.split()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `[float(val) for sublist in (row.split() for row in data) for val in sublist]` but it is much more readable (and easier to debug in the future) to keep them out on seperate lines

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is only to merge into a one-liner, you can use a generator expression (thanks to @OneCricketeer) that would generate item only when in demand and making it memory efficient than the lists:

```
flattened = [float(val) for sublist in (row.split() for row in data) for val in sublist]
```

Comment: I would write `(row.split() for row in data)` to not make a secondary list

Comment: @OneCricketeer wouldn't that create a tuple instead?

Comment: @DirtyBit No. *Commas* create tuples, not parentheses. (The exception is the empty tuple, since `()` is not a valid parenthesized expression.) Parentheses simply prevent the comma from being interpreted as some other part of Python's grammar (for instance, in the argument list to a function.)

Comment: @DirtyBit using curved brackets in comprehensions makes it a generator expression (basically a list that isn't generated in memory, but lazy evaluated). See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Comment: @OneCricketeer and hence memory efficient!

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
data = ["1 2",
        "3 4",
        "5 6",
        "7 8",
        "9 10"
        ]

rows = [float(val) for row in data for sublist in row.split() for val in sublist]
print(rows)
```

Returns:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```